# Dropwizard: access to invalid-field names when InvalidEntityException is thrown

Tags: dropwizard

Any idea/suggestion how can I get hold of invalid-field names for which InvalidEntityException is thrown? other than (if its not only the option) decoding them from the error messages (which is going to be nasty).